# Is there an analytical result for this expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have an expression
$$
\max_{\{e_i\}(i=1,\ldots,n)}\sum_k \big|(e_k,\beta)\big|^4 + 2 \big|(e_1,\alpha)\big|^2,
$$
where $\{e_i\}(i=1,\ldots,n)$ is an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{C}^n$, 
$\alpha,\beta$ are some given unit vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$.
I was wondering if there is an analytical result for it (express it as some explicit function of $|(\alpha,\beta)|$).

It may be highly improbable. If it can't be achieved, it there at least some explicit function $f(\cdot)$ satisfying
$$
\sum_k \big|(e_k,\beta)\big|^4 + 2 \big|(e_1,\alpha)\big|^2 \leq f(|(\alpha,\beta)|),
$$
where $$f(|(\alpha,\beta)|) \leq 3;\text{ and } f(|(\alpha,\beta)|) < 3 \text{ for some }|(\alpha,\beta)|?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $e_1$, write $\beta = (e_1, \beta) e_1 + \beta'$, so 
$\sum_{k > 1} |(e_k, \beta)|^4 = \sum_{k > 1} |(e_k, \beta')|^4$.  This is 
maximized when one of the $e_k$, say $e_2$, is in the direction of $\beta'$, in which case
$\sum_{k > 1} |(e_k, \beta)|^4 = \|\beta'\|^4 = (1 - |(e_1, \beta)|^2)^2$.
So now you want to choose the unit vector $e_1$ to maximize

$$ g(e_1) = |(e_1, \beta)|^4 + (1 - |(e_1, \beta)|^2)^2 + 2 |(e_1, \alpha)|^2$$

We may assume wlog $(\beta, \alpha) = \rho \ge 0$ (since phase doesn't affect $g$).
Taking $e_1 = x \beta + y \alpha$, $x$ and $y$ real, so
$x^2 + 2 \rho x y  + y^2 = 1$, and $g(e_1) = (x + \rho y)^4 + (1 - (x+\rho y)^2)^2 + 2 (\rho x + y)^2$.  Lagrange multipliers should do the rest.
I get a rather nasty result, requiring solution of a quartic in $y^2$.

$$\left( 4\,{{\rho}}^{6}-12\,{{\rho}}^{4}+12\,{{\rho}}^{2}-4
 \right) {y}^{8}+ \left( 8\,{{\rho}}^{6}-12\,{{\rho}}^{4}+4
 \right) {y}^{6}+ \left( 12\,{{\rho}}^{4}-12\,{{\rho}}^{2}
 \right) {y}^{4}+4\,{{\rho}}^{2}{y}^{2}-{{\rho}}^{2} = 0
$$